# conditionalPanel shows weird behaviour

Tags: r, shiny

Let's consider the simple tutorial example expanded by some conditionalPanels as I understood they could/should be used

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("censusVis"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Create demographic maps with 
               information from the 2010 US Census."),
      selectInput("var", 
                  label = "Choose a variable to display",
                  choices = list("Percent White" = 1,
                                 "Percent Black" = 2,
                                 "Percent Hispanic" = 3),
                  selected = 1
                  ),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.var == 1",
                       sliderInput("range", label = "Range of interest:", min = 0, max = 10, value = c(0, 10))
      ),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.var == 2",
                       sliderInput("range", label = "Range of interest:", min = 0, max = 20, value = c(0, 20))
      ),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.var == 3",
                       sliderInput("range", label = "Range of interest:", min = 0, max = 30, value = c(0, 30))
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("text1"),
      textOutput("text2")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) { 
  output$text1 <- renderText({ 
    paste("You have selected", input$var)
  })

  output$text2 <- renderText({ 
    paste("You have chosen a range that goes from",
          input$range[1], "to", input$range[2])
  })


  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As expected, when I move the slider, the range changes. But, if I make another choice and then move the slider, the output does not change. Did I misunderstood the conditionalPanel as some sort of if else if condition, or how should my example be changed?

My current solution would be to give every slider a unique inputID and use an if else if condition w.r.t `"var"` on the server side. But for a lot of possibilities this gets quite nasty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overcome this by adding a `reactive` statement and assigning different `ids` to `sliderInput` in `conditionalPanel`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(
         titlePanel("censusVis"),

sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  helpText("Create demographic maps with 
           information from the 2010 US Census."),
  selectInput("var", 
              label = "Choose a variable to display",
              choices = list("Percent White" = 1,
                             "Percent Black" = 2,
                             "Percent Hispanic" = 3),
              selected = 1
  ),
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.var == 1",
                   sliderInput("range1", label = "Range of interest:", min = 0, 
                               max = 10, value = c(0, 10))
  ),
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.var == 2",
                   sliderInput("range2", label = "Range of interest:", min = 0, 
                               max = 20, value = c(0, 20))
  ),
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.var == 3",
                   sliderInput("range3", label = "Range of interest:", min = 0, 
                               max = 30, value = c(0, 30))
  )
),
mainPanel(
  textOutput("text1"),
  textOutput("text2")
)))

server <- function(input, output) {

   someName <- reactive({
                   switch(input$var,
                          "1" = input$range1,
                          "2" = input$range2,
                          "3" = input$range3)
                        })

output$text1 <- renderText({ 
paste("You have selected", input$var)
})

output$text2 <- renderText({ 
paste("You have chosen a range that goes from",
      someName()[1], "to", someName()[2])
})


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thats a very elegant solution. Thanks.

Comment: Another thing... how would that work if I would have nested conditionalPanels?